# memory leak causing OutOfMemoryError:javaHeapSpace

Tags: java, sockets, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

below is the part code of a multi-threaded socket server java console application. when the application receives normal data(every 30 sec) heap memory is stable but as soon as data incoming frequency is increased(per second) the heap starts to grow and doesn't reduce even after the frequency decreases and throws a `out of memory error` after some time.

```
else if(rec_data_string.contains(cs2))
                    {
                    //System.out.println("1SecData"); //if one second data
/*===================extracting data from input string======================================*/
                    try{
                        String Split =null,simsplit=null,latlon=null,slat=null;
                        String[] Splitlat=null;String[] sptime=null;String[] spdate=null;String[] svel=null;
                        String[] sdist=null;String[] salt=null;String[] sbat=null;String[] Signitn=null;String[] strSSTR=null;
                        String[] sacc=null;String[] fsacc=null;
                        String EventTyp="E";
                        System.out.println("INPUT DATA FROM DEV::>"+rec_data_string);


                    {
                    try {

                        recsplit=rec_data_string.split("\\?");
                        Split=recsplit[1];
                        varsplit=Split.split("\\&");
                        simsplit=varsplit[0];
                        splstrSimNo=simsplit.split("=");
                        strSimNo=splstrSimNo[1];        //extracting data
                        lStrSimNo=strSimNo.length();    
                        latlon=varsplit[3];
                        splitlatlon=latlon.split("LON:");
                        Lon=splitlatlon[1];             //extracting data
                        slat=splitlatlon[0];
                        Splitlat =slat.split("LAT:");
                        Lat=Splitlat[1];                //extracting data
                        sptime=varsplit[1].split("=");
                        strTime=sptime[1];              //extracting data
                        spdate=varsplit[2].split("=");
                        strDate=spdate[1];              //extracting data
                        svel=varsplit[4].split("=");
                        strVel=svel[1];                 //extracting data
                        sdist=varsplit[5].split("=");
                        strDist=sdist[1];               //extracting data
                        salt=varsplit[6].split("=");
                        stralt=salt[1];                 //extracting data
                        sbat=varsplit[10].split("=");
                        strbat=sbat[1];                 //extracting data
                        Signitn=varsplit[13].split("=");
                        Ignition=Signitn[1];            //extracting data
                        strSSTR=varsplit[16].split("=");
                        SSTR=strSSTR[1];                //extracting data

                        sacc=varsplit[17].split("=");
                        fsacc=sacc[1].split(" ");
                        SSSTR=fsacc[0];                 
                        stracc=SSSTR.trim();            //extracting data



/*=========================DATA VALIDATION STARTS HERE==================================*/

                        float chklat=Float.parseFloat(Lat);
                        float chklon=Float.parseFloat(Lon);
                        //calling the function for data validation.
                        //it checks 1. if the unit id is 10 digits or not
                        //          2. if the date time and latlon variables are not null
                        //          3. if the laat lon is in given range or not 
                        //if YES.. returns valid data
                        //if NO... returns the appropriate reason handled in the else and exits the block.
                        //      1.if incorrect lat,lon--logs the instance and waits for the next data. SOCKET IS NOT CLOSED IF LAT LON IS ZERO.
                        //      2.if any other validation failure-- logs and CLOSES the socket.
                        ValResp=Validation(lStrSimNo, strDate, strTime, latlon, chklat, chklon);
                        if(ValResp=="valid data")
                        {
                            //date time conversion starts here>>>


                            sstrdate="20"+strDate.trim();
                            Date startDate =formatter1.parse(sstrdate);
                            String hh=strTime.substring(0,2);
                            String mm=strTime.substring(2,4);
                            String ss=strTime.substring(4,6);
                            sstrtime=hh+":"+mm+":"+ss;
                            String DTT=sstrdate+" "+sstrtime.trim();
                            Date startDate1 = (Date)targetformatter.parse(DTT);

                            Calendar call = Calendar.getInstance();
                            call.setTime(startDate1);
                            call.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 330); //adding 330 min to convert GMT to IST
                            String newTime = targetformatter.format(call.getTime());
                            Date startDate2 = (Date)targetformatter.parse(newTime);

                            //converting Latitude into understandable value>>>>
                            lat=LatParseCovert(Lat);

                            //converting Longitude into understandable value>>>>
                            lon=LonParseCovert(Lon);

                            //making speed parseable for tables>>>
                            double speed=Double.parseDouble(strVel);

                            //getting the previous latitude and longitude for distance calculation>>>
                            //the SP returns the previous lat,lon
                            String latlonresp=DataManager.callEIL_spGetPrvLatLon(strSimNo);
                            if(latlonresp!="5"){
                            String[] dbqry4=latlonresp.split(",");
                            prelat=Double.parseDouble(dbqry4[0]);
                            prelon=Double.parseDouble(dbqry4[1]);
                            dttime=dbqry4[2];

                            //calculating the distance between two latitudes and longitudes>>>
                            double dbldist=1.02*(DataManager.Distance(prelat, prelon, lat, lon));
                            accdbldist=Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.5f",dbldist));

                            String SD2=targetformatter.format(startDate2);
                            Date date1 = formatter2.parse(dttime);
                            Date date2 = targetformatter.parse(SD2);
                            long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
                            TimeDiff=(double)difference/(60*60*1000);


                            //this is done to keep out incorrect lat lon from inserting into table
                            //using distance=speed X time. where the max spd is 120kmph.>>>
                            //if the accdbldist is greater than maximun calculated distance it can move,the variable is set to 0>>>
                                double spdcalc=120; //speed in km/hr
                                if(accdbldist>TimeDiff*spdcalc)
                                {
                                    accdbldist=0;

                                }

                            DataManager.callEIL_spGpsDataSecbySec(strSimNo, lat, lon, speed, NoS, startDate2, Ignition, accdbldist, EventTyp, stracc,strbat);   
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            //if no previous lat,lon found,inserting data into table as it is the first data from the device>>>
                            //distance will be zero>>>
                            accdbldist=0;
                            //tbl GPSDATA insertion if the data is the first data from the device
                            DataManager.callEIL_spGpsDataSecbySec(strSimNo, lat, lon, speed, NoS, startDate2, Ignition, accdbldist, EventTyp, stracc,strbat);
                            }

                            //updating tblsstr only if SSTR value satisfies the below condition
                            if(!SSTR.equals("NULL")&&(!SSTR.equals(null)))
                            {
                            DataManager.callEIL_spSSTR(strSimNo, startDate2, SSTR, lat, lon, speed, NoS, Ignition, accdbldist);
                            }
                            accdbldist=0.0d;
                        }
                        else if(ValResp=="Incorrect lat-lon"){
                            //code to exit if lat,lon not correct
                            //System.out.println("INCORRECT LAT LON");
                            LogManager.logError("incorrect coordinates:"+strSimNo+","+chklat+","+chklon);   
                            }

                        else{
                            //code to exit if strDate,strTime,latlon is null
                            //System.out.println("MALFORMED PACKET");
                            LogManager.logError("Packet Incorrect: "+rec_data_string+","+conn.getInetAddress());
                            conn.close();
                            System.gc();

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        LogManager.logException(e.getMessage()+Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
                    }
                    }//for block ends here
                    }

/*==================================================VALIDATION ENDS HERE=======================================================*/
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        LogManager.logException(rec_data_string+e.getMessage()+Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));

                    }
                    }//else if loop 1sec data ending here
```

please tell how to solve and help me keep the heap stable.

Comment: Have you tried to increase heap size?

Comment: @AnkitTripathi yes i did. but once i increase the number of users and each of them start sending data with the increased frequency the heap keeps on growing untill the `OutOfMemoryError` occours.

Comment: You need to look at the heap dump on OOME and see where the bulk of data was being retained.